# is there a way to create a button that downloads the open html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a html page that is interactive. Sort of html5 app for my phone. I want to be able to save the session and transfer it between devices. The simplest way is to save the page while using it to some cloud service. The problem is that on mobile platform I don't have the save option in the menu. I can install an addon for that, but I wondered if I can add a button that does that for me.

So, how can I create a button in an html page that opens the currently open page (including the modifications).

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Instead of saving the page itself maybe you could save only the unique data and load that into the app.

Comment: The idea is to have everything on a single file. Also, the html page updates itself (yes, this is virus like feature, that's why I'm not going to distribute this).

Comment: I'm open to different solutions, of course.